# E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Download/my_file.JPEG (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have tried every single way, but I haven't got output. It is showing an error I have tried various way.

```
File imgFile = new File( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "/my_file.JPEG");
    if(!(imgFile==null)){
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getPath());
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        Log.d("ashwiniiii","ashwiniii");
    }
    else {
        myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    }
```

Comment: anyone with a solution ???

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Consider reviewing your question according to SO [How-to-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guideline.

Comment: it might be a good idea to link other SO questions you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 File imgFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

    if(!(imgFile==null)){
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getPath() + "/my_file.JPEG");
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }
    else {
        myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    }
```

Comment: Is this the solution to your problem or an edit to your question?

Comment: Hi Wini, you have post two code samples, one in the question section and one in the answer section. As the original poster of a question, you should never post an answer *unless* it is the solution to your problem. In all other cases, either *edit* your original question or add a comment to it. Because of _how_ you posted here, we really don't how to help you because we cannot determine what is what.